# Changed the Edmx and got errors

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I tried to change the Entities Table Name and encountered an error.
I just renamed **TblRecord** as the name was from the Table Name

What is the mistake here and how to resolve it ?

---

**Error :**

```
+       _innerException {"The specified table does not exist. [ Records ]"} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}
```

---

**The Edmx File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Xz.Business.Matches.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" ProviderManifestToken="4.0" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="XzBusinessMatchesStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="Records" EntityType="Xz.Business.Matches.Store.Records" store:Type="Tables" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Records">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Record" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Record" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" />
          <Property Name="Relations" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="450" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Xz.Business.Matches" Alias="Self" p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="RecordzEntities" p1:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="Records" EntityType="Xz.Business.Matches.TblRecord" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="TblRecord">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Record" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Record" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="Relations" Type="String" MaxLength="450" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="XzBusinessMatchesStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="RecordzEntities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Records">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Xz.Business.Matches.TblRecord">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Records">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Record" ColumnName="Record" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Relations" ColumnName="Relations" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="True" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="True" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

*This is EF5 & VS12*

Comment: Undo your changes and use the edmx designer to make your changes.

Comment: this is a bit late for undo, although no problem to generate everything from ground up. But want to understand a bit more the details and manually editing some pieces like what I mentioned.

Comment: Did you rename the table in the database? The exception you get is thrown from the database (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException). It makes me think that your edmx may be correct as EF did not choke on it but the database does not have the Records table.

Comment: Hi Pawel, No the renaming happened in the auto generated entities. You couldn't find anything wrong within the edmx I posted ?! Is it correct ? I'm going to regenerate everything...

Answer (score 0):

If you're renamed the table in the DB you will need to update the mapping in the EDMX. The error message is self describing.

Failing that you could just delete the model `TblRecord` from the edmx designer and re-add it with the new name `Record`.

Comment: Seems that didn't rename it the right way, I used the Replace Window of the VS. So now wanted to know which piece is renamed that shouldn't be renamed.

Comment: Also don't know when adding a model how to define the name as you said. the name of the model here was xModel, how is it related to these TblRecord and record ?